# How to create a method on a prototype that combines the first and last names into a full name

Tags: javascript, function, methods, prototype

I'm taking a JavaScript class and I need some help with some code that I'm trying to complete.

One of the stipulations to gettin %100 percent on this is to combine a first name and last name by creating a method on a prototype. I've tried but I can't seem to get it properly.

```
    (function(){
        const fullname = document.getElementById('fullname');
        const type = document.getElementById('type');
        const ability = document.getElementById('ability');

// create your Skier object here.

function Person (firstname, lastname, type, ability){
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
  this.type = type;
  this.ability = ability;
}

var skier = new Person('John', 'Smith', 'Snowboarder', 'Advanced');

// Then, un-comment the lies below and replace the empty strings with the correct code to display your person's name, type and ability in the HTML output window. 

      fullname.textContent = skier.firstname+' '+skier.lastname;   
      type.textContent = skier.type;
      ability.textContent = skier.ability;
 }())
```

Any help with combining the first and last names using that method/protoype system is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new `getFullName` method to the `Person` prototype, making it accessible to all `Person` instances in the following way:

```
Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
  return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
}
```